# With tensorflow I have a dict of image information. How do I train features in those images?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm reading images from a directory using each folder name as the label.  Each element in a list of images contains a dictionary like this:

```
{'image': array([[[152, 117,  89],
    [150, 115,  87],
    ...etc]], dtype=uint8),
'label': 'dog',
'path': 'images/dog/20311lpr.jpg'}
```

I want to train tensorflow to learn the similarities between all of the images in each label so later I can use another script to check an image against this data and tell me what label or labels that new image should have.

What should I be learning/reading about next?

I have a bunch of images like this:

> ```
> $ find images -type f
> images/cat/images.jpeg
> images/cat/images-1.jpeg
> images/cat/Unknown.jpeg
> ...etc
> images/dog/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg
> images/dog/hungry-spaniel-eats-from-bowlimage.gif
> images/dog/image02.PNG
> images/dog/20311lpr.jpg
> ...etc
> ```

My script, so far, looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

 import argparse, os
 from pprint import pprint
 import tensorflow as tf

 os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2' # Don't show warnings

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Options")
 parser.add_argument('imagedir', default='./images', type=str)
 args = parser.parse_args()

 def main():
     images_w_labels = get_all_images(args.imagedir)
     pprint(images_w_labels[-1]) # Print the last one

 def _process_image(filename):
     if filename.lower().endswith('png'):
         imgdata = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(filename))
     elif filename.lower().endswith('gif'):
         imgdata = tf.image.decode_gif(tf.read_file(filename))
     else:
         imgdata = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(filename))
     sess = tf.Session()
     imgdata = sess.run(imgdata)
     return imgdata

 def get_all_images(imagedir):
     images = []
     for root, subdir, files in os.walk(imagedir):
         if len(files) == 0: continue
         for file in files:
             images.append({
                 'path': os.path.join(root,file),
                 'label': os.path.split(root)[-1],
                 'image': _process_image(os.path.join(root,file))
                 })
     return images

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

The output of this script, so far, is below:

```
$ ./build_image.data.py images
{'image': array([[[152, 117,  89],
        [150, 115,  87],
        [149, 114,  86],
        ..., 
        [143, 104,  61],
        [143, 104,  61],
        [144, 105,  62]],

       [[151, 117,  89],
        [150, 116,  88],
        [149, 115,  87],
        ..., 
        [142, 103,  60],
        [142, 103,  60],
        [143, 104,  61]],

       [[149, 118,  89],
        [148, 117,  88],
        [147, 116,  87],
        ..., 
        [142, 103,  62],
        [142, 103,  62],
        [142, 103,  62]],

       ..., 
       [[163, 136, 106],
        [164, 137, 107],
        [164, 137, 108],
        ..., 
        [  9,  13,  12],
        [ 10,  14,  13],
        [ 10,  14,  13]],

       [[162, 137, 106],
        [162, 137, 106],
        [162, 137, 107],
        ..., 
        [ 12,  14,  13],
        [ 13,  15,  14],
        [ 13,  15,  14]],

       [[161, 136, 105],
        [161, 136, 105],
        [162, 137, 107],
        ..., 
        [ 13,  15,  14],
        [ 13,  15,  14],
        [ 14,  16,  15]]], dtype=uint8),
 'label': 'dog',
 'path': 'images/dog/20311lpr.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feed numpy array to tensorflow placeholders using a feed_dict, which is an argument to both `session.run` and `tensor.eval`. To do so, though, you'll need a model.